# Is it permissible to add profit without manager's knowledge?

Tags: practical-islam, money, cheating

Detail: For example, a salesman makes a sales invoice of SAR-2,600/- and gets the cash from the customer & then he destroys the invoice and evidence then makes a new Invoice of SAR-2,400 and keeps SAR-200 for himself and shows his manager the Invoice of SAR-2,400/- and then gives the money to his manager. Is this permissible in Islam. What is this called bribery, stealing, cheating etc.

Comment: It's cheating, of course. I think it's quite obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you explained the story, it is inferred from the matter that it is completely a haram or forbidden practice. Because according to your example as you gave it:

" a salesman makes a sales invoice of SAR-2,600/- and gets the cash from the customer & then he destroys the invoice and evidence then makes a new Invoice of SAR-2,400 and keeps SAR-200 for himself and shows his manager the Invoice of SAR-2,400/- and then gives the money to his manager"

Thus it indicates that it is cheating as Mr. Najeeb said it. In other word, it means it is a kind of rubbery(stealing) as I figured it out. And we should notice that stealing is not only stealing the wallets, or going to the places of people hiddenly and so on, then stealing can be in hiding or changing the facts or such as you said too.

Answer (score -1):

This is definitely an impermissible thing and as a result it is a haram thing that looks a kind of deceiving if you want to cheat your boss in order to obtaining more money. Accordingly I strongly recommend you leave it although it has much profit. Because as I stated before this is haram and there are many hadiths (beside the quran)

Look at the following hadith from Imam Sadiq (pbuh) as a hadith about haram property, so don't forget that there are many verses and ahadith regarding haram property that I give only one example here.

> إذا أرادَ أَحَدُكُم أَن يُستَجابَ لَهُ فَليُطَيِّب كَسبَهُ و َليَخرُج
>   مِن مَظالِمِ النّاسِ ، وَ إِنَّ اللّه‏َ لا يَرفَعُ إِلَيهِ دُعاء عَبدٍ
>   وَفى بَطنِهِ حَرامٌ أَو عِندَهُ مَظلَمَةٌ لأِحَدٍ مِن خَلقِهِ؛
>
> Whoever wants his (her) wishes to be granted, should has halal
>   obtaining…

You can follow the source below in order to see more ahadith about haram property

http://www.aviny.com/hadis-mozooee/eghtesadi/haram.aspx